# where to put controller code for partials you render from different views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A newbie question:

I have a partial that I'm loading on a website on different pages.

That partial needs some data, so in the controller of the parent view I do the query:
@properties = Property.find(:all)

I pass the query results to the partial in the view using :locals

Now, I would like to render the same partial from another view. This view has a different controller. Do I have to repeat the query in that controller also? Or can I have a separate controller for partials I use one more places in the website. In this last case, how do I indicate which controller to use in the view when I put the render command?

Or should I use somethink different than partials for this kind of use?

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy the code to set up the partial's data, but you *would* need to hoist it into a controller that your two controllers inherit from.  Normally, this would be your `ApplicationController`.  Define a method in there that loads the data you need.  For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ... your code ...

protected

  def load_partial_data
    @properties = Property.find(:all)
  end

end
```

Now to actually call this method you have two options:

1. If all your controllers need this data, add a `before_filter` to your `ApplicationController` like `before_filter :load_partial_data`
2. Otherwise, add the `before_filter` to *just* the controllers that actually need to load the data.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

How i would solve this, is to define a new file inside your `lib` folder, with a meaningful name. For now i will just use `does_as_shared.rb`:

```
module DoesAsShared
  def setup_shared_data
    @shared_data = ...do something useful here ...
  end
end
```

and then inside your controllers that need that code you write:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  include DoesAsShared

  def index
    setup_shared_data
    .. and do some more stuff ...
  end
end
```

The advantage of this code is that the shared code is limited to those controllers that really need it. And at the same time it is pretty readable: the include statement, given that the name is chosen well, clearly indicates what functionality is included.